# Loop colnames basis a vector pattern

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I wish to filter basis column names basis a vector and subsequently bind them together.

This is my data frame -

```
df = data.frame("Applefor_yes" = 1:4,
                "Applefor_no" = 2:5,
                "Bananfor_yes" = 1:4,
                "Bananfor_no" = 2:5)

   Applefor_yes Applefor_no Bananfor_yes Bananfor_no
1            1           2            1           2
2            2           3            2           3
3            3           4            3           4
4            4           5            4           5
```

I want the output to look like this.

```
     fruit yes no
1 Applefor   1  2
2 Applefor   2  3
3 Applefor   3  4
4 Applefor   4  5
5 Bananfor   1  2
6 Bananfor   2  3
7 Bananfor   3  4
8 Bananfor   4  5
```

In short, I want to loop the column names basis a vector c("Bananfor", "Applefor")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution

```
pat <- c("yes","no")
u <- data.frame(setNames(lapply(pat, function(x) unlist(subset(df,select = grep(x,names(df))))),pat))
dfout <- data.frame(fruit = gsub("_.*","",rownames(u)),u,row.names = NULL)
```

or

```
dfout <- do.call(rbind,
                 c(make.row.names = F,
                   Map(function(x) data.frame(fruit = gsub("_.*","",names(x)),
                                              setNames(x,gsub(".*_","",names(x)))),
                       split(unclass(df),gsub("(.*)_.*","\\1",names(df))))))
```

such that

```
> dfout
     fruit yes no
1 Applefor   1  2
2 Applefor   2  3
3 Applefor   3  4
4 Applefor   4  5
5 Bananfor   1  2
6 Bananfor   2  3
7 Bananfor   3  4
8 Bananfor   4  5
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` specifying `names_to` and `names_sep` argument.

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = everything(),
                        names_to = c("fruit", ".value"), 
                        names_sep = "_")

#  fruit      yes    no
#  <chr>    <int> <int>
#1 Applefor     1     2
#2 Bananfor     1     2
#3 Applefor     2     3
#4 Bananfor     2     3
#5 Applefor     3     4
#6 Bananfor     3     4
#7 Applefor     4     5
#8 Bananfor     4     5
```